# How to translate this code from Intel(nasm) to AT&T(gas) syntax?

Tags: assembly, nasm, att

```
gdt64:
  dq 0 ; zero entry
.code: equ $ - gdt64
  ; 0x08 kernel CS 0x8
  ; bits set: descriptor type, present, executable, 64bit
  dq (1<<53) | (1<<47) |                     (1<<44) | (1<<43) ; kernel
  ; 0x10 user CS
  ; works when its set to kernel mode, but when in user mode, it doesnt, duh
  ;dq (1<<53) | (1<<47) |                     (1<<44) | (1<<43) ; kernel
  dq (1<<53) | (1<<47) | (1<<46) | (1<<45) | (1<<44) | (1<<43)
```

I understand that dq is .long. And I can translate first part of this:

```
gdt64:
  .long 0 // zero entry
.code = . - gdt64
```

But How to translate line like this:

```
  dq (1<<53) | (1<<47) | (1<<46) | (1<<45) | (1<<44) | (1<<43)
```

Comment: Not an assembly expert, but wouldn't it be just a number with respective bits set?

Comment: Have you tried `.quad (1<<53) | (1<<47) | (1<<46) | (1<<45) | (1<<44) | (1<<43)`?

Comment: Yes I think it is a number with respective bit set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `dq` in NASM assembles an 8-byte quadword, whereas `.long` in x86 GAS is a 4-byte doubleword, so that's not what you want.  The correct equivalent is `.quad`.

Your `(1<<53) | ...` is just an arithmetic expression using C-like shift and bitwise operators, and `dq (1 << 53) | ...` assembles a quadword having as its value the result of this expression.  GAS accepts this syntax as well, so you can simply write

```
.quad (1<<53) | (1<<47) | (1<<46) | (1<<45) | (1<<44) | (1<<43)
```