# How do I convert AT&T syntax to NASM syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, att

How do I convent  the below AT&T syntax to NASM syntax so NASM can understand it?

```
    .file   "kernel.c"
    .globl  _videoMemory
    .data
    .align 4
_videoMemory:
    .long   753664
    .globl  _screenWidth
    .section .rdata,"dr"
    .align 4
_screenWidth:
    .long   80
    .globl  _screenHeight
    .align 4
_screenHeight:
    .long   25
    .text
    .globl  _cls
    .def    _cls;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_cls:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    jmp L2
L3:
    movl    _videoMemory, %edx
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movb    $32, (%eax)
    movl    _videoMemory, %eax
    movl    -4(%ebp), %edx
    addl    $1, %edx
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movb    $7, (%eax)
    addl    $2, -4(%ebp)
L2:
    movl    $80, %edx
    movl    $25, %eax
    imull   %edx, %eax
    addl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    jg  L3
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
    .globl  _strlen
    .def    _strlen;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_strlen:
LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    jmp L5
L6:
    addl    $1, -4(%ebp)
    addl    $1, 8(%ebp)
L5:
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movzbl  (%eax), %eax
    testb   %al, %al
    jne L6
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE1:
    .globl  _printchar
    .def    _printchar; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_printchar:
LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $4, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movb    %al, -4(%ebp)
    movl    _videoMemory, %edx
    movl    12(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movzbl  -4(%ebp), %eax
    movb    %al, (%edx)
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE2:
    .globl  _print
    .def    _print; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_print:
LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _strlen
    movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    jmp L10
L11:
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %eax, %eax
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movzbl  (%eax), %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    movl    %ecx, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _printchar
    addl    $1, -4(%ebp)
L10:
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    cmpl    -8(%ebp), %eax
    jb  L11
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE3:
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "a\0"
    .text
    .globl  _kmain
    .def    _kmain; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_kmain:
LFB4:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $8, %esp
    call    _cls
    movl    $LC0, %eax
    movsbl  %al, %eax
    movl    $1, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _printchar
    nop
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE4:
    .ident  "GCC: (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0"
```

I've searched but I haven't found any translator for AT&T syntax to NASM syntax yet.

If you can help me translate this code, provide any software that can, or a tutorial that helps with this, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: If you wish to pass off compiler generated assembly code as your own, this will not suffice.

Comment: Part of the problem is searching on the wrong name.  This is AT&T syntax (generated by GCC), not "ATS".  I've never heard of "ATS" syntax.  Multiple Q&As exist, like [Translating AT&T to INTEL syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24926280) / [Converting AT&T syntax program to intel syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34038812).  [How to translate this code from Intel(nasm) to AT&T(gas) syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65938270) covers a bit about directives.

Comment: It would probably be easier to start with GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix`, like from `gcc -masm=intel`.  ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116), although you need the `section` and data stuff to actually be able to assemble it.)  Or use a NASM-syntax disassembler for the code parts ([How to disassemble a binary executable in Linux to get the assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33978857) shows how to use `objconv`) so you only have to hand-translate the data sections.

Answer (score 1):

In AT&T, `%` indicates a register. NASM simply figures that out, so remove the `%`s. AT&T has immediate values start with `$`, whereas NASM figures it out, so remove the `$`s.

In AT&T, the order is `instruction source, destination`, whereas in NASM it is `instruction destination, source`, so swap them.

AT&T: `movl (%ecx),%eax`.
NASM: `mov eax, [ecx]

In AT&T, `()` is the memory operand. In NASM, `[]` is the memory operand.

AT&T: %segreg:disp(base,index,scale) == disp + base + index*scale, where scale defaults to 1 if absent.
NASM: [segreg:base+index*scale+disp]

AT&T: subl -0x20(%ebx,%ecx,0x4),%eax

NASM: sub eax,[ebx+ecx*4h-20h]

AT&T uses suffixes on instructions to determine memory size, whereas NASM uses words before memory addresses when necessary.

AT&T: 8 bits is a 'b' suffix, 16 bits is a 'w' suffix, 32 bits is a 'l' suffix, and 64 bits is a 'q' suffix.
NASM: 8 bits is `byte`, 16 bits is `word`, 32 bits is `dword`, and 64 bits is `qword`.

In AT&T, global labels can start with alphabetic characters or `_`. In NASM, global labels can start with alphanumeric characters, `@`, `?`, and `_`. In AT&T, local labels start with numbers. In NASM, local labels start with `.`.

In AT&T, directives start with `.`. In NASM primitive directives can be in-between `[]`, but they don’t have to be.

Instead of searching for “converting NASM to AT&T“, search for “converting Intel to AT&T”. NASM uses Intel syntax.

This should be enough to help you get started.

Some people make GCC and GAS use Intel syntax for the assembly. Although, from what I’ve read, it isn’t very reliable.

You could assemble the AT&T syntaxes code, then disassemble the binary file with NASM’s ndisasm program. That would make the data section harder to read, but it would work.

Let me know, or make an edit, if any of this information is inaccurate.

Because of this question, I have started a GitHub [repository](https://github.com/TacoBlayno/assembly-syntax-converter) meant to convert assembly syntaxes. Perhaps you would be interested in contributing. We could negotiate which programming language to use, I haven’t made much progress as of writing this (after all, I did just make it).

Comment: NASM directives like `global foo` or `section .data` don't start with `@`; in fact I can't think of any case in NASM where you'd use `@` at the start of something.  Also, you're missing `code formatting` in some of the early parts, so `*` gets processed as the italics markdown.

Comment: Fixed it, and I can’t think of any place where I’d use @ at the beginning of something in NASM either. That was probably a different assembler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info has another list of syntax differences, and links to more Q&As.  Also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info  has some stuff about the different flavours of Intel syntax, like NASM (`mov edi, symbol` is a mov-immediate)  vs. GNU `.intel_syntax noprefix` and MASM (`mov edi, symbol` is a load).

Comment: "NASM: segreg:[base+index*scale+disp]" Recent NASM may support this but traditionally the `segreg:` belongs into the brackets, not before them. "In NASM, global labels can start with alphanumeric characters, and _." Global is not the same as nonlocal. And labels must start with a non-decimal-digit text in NASM normally, as digits indicate numeric operands. Some other texts like `_`, `@`, `?`, `.` are also allowed in labels.

Comment: "… traditionally the segreg: belongs into the brackets, not before them." Can you give an example of this?

Comment: like `[fs: 0x28]`, or https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3 has another example.

Comment: What is the segreg: supposed to mean?